# How can I use a PHP Session to use a Variable in next php script?

Tags: php, session, variables

I want to make a variable in one php script which I can then use in another php script.

How can I use php sessions to do this?

How would I define and then retrieve a php session variable?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['your_var'] = $value;
```

in second page

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['your_var'];
```

i suggest you learn from here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

The code above has to appear above any html codes. You have to call that again on the page you are going to use. Then you can do `$_SESSION['variable'] = 'value';` to save the variable. Then to call that variable, you can do `echo $_SESSION['variable'];`